# How to make my prolog code to get the shortest path?

Tags: prolog, shortest-path

I wrote several lines of code to calculate the shortest path:

```
:- auto_table.

link(a,b,2).
link(c,b,1).
link(a,c,2).
link(c,d,2).
link(d,b,3).
link(a,e,2).
link(e,b,2).
link(a,f,1).

link(X,Y,C) :- link(Y,X,C).

:- table short_path(_,_,_,po('<'/2)).

% P is the next node in the path
short_path(X, Y, P, C) :-
    link(X, Y, C),
    P = Y.
short_path(X, Y, P, C) :-
    link(X, N, C2),
    short_path(N, Y, _, C3),
    C is C2 + C3,
    P = N.
```

The output is like this:

```
P = f
C = 6;

P = e
C = 7;

P = b
C = 5;

P = c
C = 4;
```

How could I only get the shortest path with a minimum of C as the output?

Comment: In your output, what did you query and use for `X` and `Y`? One way to get the shortest path would be to use `setof/3` to collect the solutions `C-P` you get from `short_path`, then `reverse/2` and select the first element of the result.

Comment: X is the source and Y is the destination, I used X=a, Y=d in my query.

Comment: I tried to use setof(C,short_path(a,d,P,C),Bag), however I could not get a list of all the possible values of C. How could I collect the solutions C-P?

Comment: `setof(C-P, short_path(a,d,P,C), Bag)`.

Comment: You can also do a stackoverflow.com search for `[prolog] shortest path` and look at a number of questions previously posted on this topic for ideas.

Comment: Oops, ignore my comment about `reverse/2`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answers. I have one more question: how to get the first element in a list?

Comment: For a list `L = [H|T]`, `H` is the first element. `T` is the rest of the list (the tail) as a list. If you don't care about the tail, then just `[H|_]`.